# How to get only 1 submit button to trigger a function in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have four different types of submit buttons below:

```
<form id="QandA" action="register.php" method="post">

<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' />

<input type='submit' name='submitVideoBtn' class='sbtnvideo' value='Upload' />

<input type='submit' name='submitAudioBtn' class='sbtnaudio' value='Upload' />

<input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" />

</form>
```

Now I have a function below which is suppose to handle what happens after a submit button is clicked:

```
    $(function() {
    myClickHandler=function(e)
        {
            if (!validation())
                return false;

            if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" ))
                return false;

            $.ajax({
                url: "insertQuestion.php",
                data: $("#QandA").serialize(),
                async: false,
                type: "POST"
            });

            return true;
        };

$('#QandA').submit(myClickHandler);


    });
```

Now at the moment all the above submit buttons trigger the event above. I only want the `id="submitBtn"` submit button to trigger the above function. I don't want the other submit buttons to touch this function. My question is how can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

```
$(function() {
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
myClickHandler=function(e)
    {
        if (!validation())
            return false;

        if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" ))
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            url: "insertQuestion.php",
            data: $("#QandA").serialize(),
            async: false,
            type: "POST"
        });

        return true;
    };
});    
});
```

Comment: You skipped the code that you attached the click handler.

Comment: @Musa I updated code to include this

Comment: Don’t forget that you can submit a form in several ways, not just by clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you attach the click handler to the buttons in your code?

Anyway, the smart thing with jQuery is that simple handlers are already made for you. You can simply attach a click-handler to an element like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
      //... Your code here
  });
});
```

[jQuery click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Complete code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    if (!validation())
      return false;

    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" ))
      return false;

    $.ajax({
        url: "insertQuestion.php",
        data: $("#QandA").serialize(),
        async: false,
        type: "POST"
    });
    return true;
  });
});
```

Note that the ajax call will be executed asynchronously, so `return true` might be called before the ajax call has returned. See [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). (You need to apply a success function).

Comment: I updated code to include how event was fired. Just got a problem though, when I click on the `#submitBtn`, it doesn' go through the validation or show confirmation as it should do, it just performs the action and navigates to next page. Why is this?

Comment: Remove the myClickHandler=function(e){} wrapper. You should also read the jQuery documentation, to understand it a little better.

Comment: Can I quickly ask about ajax success function, if I don't want to really perform anything on success then was can I put in success function? This is because the ajax would be running in the background

Comment: You dont have to use it. Just leave it out :)